# Listview items are shuffling on scroll when 2 custom layouts called in ListView

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, viewgroup

I am calling 2 Layouts in 1 Listview

One is Linear for textView and editText and the other is just a single spinner

However, when I try to call the items in the Linear layout through program(code given below), 
the items are shuffled or either relocated from the sequence everytime the list is scrolled.

There is no error shown, but somehow this happens.

I want the list to be called once and stay in sequence.

Any help is highly appreciable.  Here below is my code

**Activity:**

**Fillup_Details.java**

```
public class Fillup_Details extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ListView listView;
        Spinner spinner;
        ArrayList<ListViemItems> listViemItemses; 

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fillup__details);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listFillupDetails);
            spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnrFillupDetails);
            setTitle("Fill-Up Details");
            loadFillupDetails();

        }

        public void loadFillupDetails() {
            listViemItemses = new ArrayList<ListViemItems>();
            ListViemItems items1 = new ListViemItems();
            items1.setListItems("ListItem1");
            items1.setOddoreven(0);
            listViemItemses.add(items1);

            ListViemItems items2 = new ListViemItems();
            items2.setListItems("ListItem2");
            items2.setOddoreven(0);
            listViemItemses.add(items2);

            //.....many more objects


            ListViemItems itemspnr = new ListViemItems();
            itemspnr.setSpinnerItems("Spinner1");
            itemspnr.setOddoreven(1);
            listViemItemses.add(itemspnr);

                    FillupDetailsList fillupDetailsList = new FillupDetailsList(Fillup_Details.this, listViemItemses);
                    listView.setAdapter(fillupDetailsList);


        } 
    }
```

**Adapter**

**FillupDetailsList.java**

```
class FillupDetailsList extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String TAGGGG = "FillupDetailsList";
    Context context;
    String[] spnrItemasas =new String[]{"a","b"} ;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =null;
    View view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<ListViemItems> listViemItems;
    int type;
    private static final int TYPE_LIST_ITEMS = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SPINNER_ITEMS= 1;
    public FillupDetailsList(Context context, ArrayList<ListViemItems> listViemItems) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.listViemItems=listViemItems;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return listViemItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        Spinner spinner;
        TextView txtItem;
        EditText edtTextItem;
        int ref;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(listViemItems.get(position).getOddoreven()==0){

            type=TYPE_LIST_ITEMS;
        }else if(listViemItems.get(position).getOddoreven()==1){
            type=TYPE_SPINNER_ITEMS;
        }
        return type;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(convertView==null){
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            Log.d(TAGGGG, "getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type){
                case TYPE_LIST_ITEMS:

                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fillup_details_layout,null);
                    viewHolder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFillupDetails);
                    viewHolder.edtTextItem = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtFillupDetails);
                    viewHolder.txtItem.setText(listViemItems.get(position).getListItems());

                    break;
                case TYPE_SPINNER_ITEMS:
                    ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adptrSpnrItem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_item, spnrItemasas);
                    adptrSpnrItem.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fillup_details_layout_spinner,viewGroup,false);
                    viewHolder.spinner = (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spnrFillupDetails);
                    viewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adptrSpnrItem);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else {
            viewHolder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Obviously it's because you are doing nothing in `getView` when `convertView!=null`

Comment: So what do u suggest  I should do ? @selvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, all I had to do was do the following changes in the switch case

```html
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_LIST_ITEMS:
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fillup_details_layout, null);
                }
                viewHolder.txtItem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFillupDetails);
                ListViemItems detail_position = listViemItems.get(position);
                viewHolder.txtItem.setText(detail_position.getListItems());
                break;
            case TYPE_SPINNER_ITEMS:
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fillup_details_layout_spinner, null);
                }
                ListViemItems detail_position2 = listViemItems.get(position);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adptrSpnrItem =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_item, detail_position2.getSpinnerItems());
                adptrSpnrItem.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);

                viewHolder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spnrFillupDetails);
                viewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adptrSpnrItem);
                break;
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```